# Building a URL with JSON data as a query string parameter value

Tags: php

I have this data

```
$data = array('username' => 'myname',
              'password' => 'mypass'
           );
$json = json_encode($data);
```

How can i pass the json as a variable to a url that looks like this

```
'http://example.com/login/?data='
```

this is what i have tried and get '400: data not passed' error

```
$data = array('username' => 'myname',
          'password' => 'mypass'
       );

$data_string = json_encode($data);
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://example.com/login/?data='); //also 'http://example.com/login/'
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Accept: application/json',
            'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string)
        ));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);

// Exec
$response = curl_exec($curl);
$info = curl_getinfo($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any data used in the query string should be [URL-encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).

```
$url = 'http://example.com/login/' . http_build_query([
    'data' => json_encode([
        'username' => 'myname',
        'password' => 'mypass'
    ])
]);
```

[`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) will take an associative array of parameters, and apply all the proper encodings, building the whole query string for you.

The URL returned:

```
http://example.com/login/data=%7B%22username%22%3A%22myname%22%2C%22password%22%3A%22mypass%22%7D
```

Comment: @Marth Well, you don't need POST, since you've put all the data in the URL, but here:  http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples.php#88055  If you actually wanted to POST the data, don't include it in the URL... just send the JSON as the POST body.  Much easier to deal with, and then you don't run into any arbitrary length restrictions.

Comment: how can i see the status like (400,200 ...) ?

Comment: @Marth `curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE)`  http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php

Comment: @Marth I don't know what you're asking at this point.  You originally indicated you wanted the data in the URL.  Do you want it in the URL or do you want to send it as the POST body?  You're sort of doing both, and we don't know what the server side expects so you'll have to determine that.

Comment: i want to post the data and get response

Comment: @Marth Right, but does the data belong in the query string or post body?

Comment: it belongs to a post body

Comment: @Marth Alright, that's extremely different than your original question.  In any case, your code looks correct to me.  If the back-end doesn't like it, then maybe it's because you still have `data=` in the query string.  Remove it.  If it still doesn't work, I'm not sure how to help you because we don't know what the backend needs, specifically.  Only you know that.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible to do this, you are pretty much there.

```
$data = array('username' => 'myname',
              'password' => 'mypass'
           );
$json = json_encode($data);

$url = 'http://example.com/login/?data=' . urlencode($json);
```

This will be a safe url that can do what ever you want with it.